How to do 301 redirect on a wordpress website
I want to set up a 301 redirect on my WordPress website to redirect the page at https://www.captivix.com/solutions/dynamics-365-business-central-implementation to https://www.captivix.com/services/microsoft-dynamics-business-central-implementation/. However, I prefer not to use any plugins, as they can slow down the website. Could someone provide a custom code solution for this?
Thanks in advance.
I tried doing it using a plugin but then I made up my mind to not use any plugin.

If you are using nginx, please try nginx maps.
Eg:
map $request_uri $new_uri {
    /solutions/dynamics-365-business-central-implementation /services/microsoft-dynamics-business-central-implementation;
}


Ok let me try this. Thanks for your help.
